Uniqueness and stability of equilibrium

Two points $P_1,P_2$ of mass $m$ move constrained respectively to $y=x^2, y=x^2-1$ in a vertical plane $xy$. Points are connected with a spring with constant $k>0$, and rest's length equal zero. Prove that there's only one equilibrium and that is stable.

Here's my attempt, I choose two coordinates $p$ for $P_1$ and $q$ for $P_2$ so I have
$$P_1 =(p,p^2), \qquad P_2 = (q,q^2-1)$$
I want to use Lagrange-Dirichlet for equilibrium stability so the potential energy of the system
$$V = mgp^2+mg(q^2-1)+\frac{1}{2}k[(p-q)^2+(p^2-q^2+1)^2]$$
I know equilibrium configuration in dynamical system with potential energy are critical points of potential energy
$$\nabla V(p,q) = \begin{pmatrix}2mgp + k(p-q)+2kp(p^2-q^2+1)\\
2mgq - k(p-q)-2kq(p^2-q^2+1)\end{pmatrix}^T$$
And I can easily see that $\nabla V (0,0) = (0,0)$ but how can I prove uniqueness? I've double checked my calculations a couple time and I think are correct, maybe I'm missing some simplifications. Thank you for the help!

The uniqueness comes from the fact that there are no other solutions to $\nabla V=0$. Solve the system of equations $\nabla V=0$ and you will find $p=q=0$ is the only solution.

@JoshB. I've tried to solve it explicitly but to me seems thats calculations get way out of hand. I'm searching for something a little bit elegant or faster... I refuse to think that brute force calculation it's the only solution.

There is not just one equilibrium to this problem. It turns out that you may have other equilibria if the spring constant $k$ is large enough. The main way to demonstrate this is by actually solving the problem of $\nabla V=0$.
You already have
$$
\nabla V=\begin{pmatrix}
2mgp+k(p-q)+2kp(p^2-q^2+1) \\
2mgq-k(p-q)-2kq(p^2-q^2+1)\end{pmatrix}=0
$$
Notice that we have a $p-q$ term, as well as a $p^2-q^2=(p+q)(p-q)$ term. Also notice that if we add these equations and subtract them as well, we get more $p+q$ and $p-q$ terms. This motivates us to create two new equations, one where we add the equations and one where we subtract. The new equations read
$$
2mg(p+q)+2k(p-q)((p+q)(p-q)+1)=0, \\
2mg(p-q)+2k(p-q)+2k(p+q)((p+q)(p-q)+1)=0
$$
Letting $u=p+q$ and $v=p-q$,
$$
2mgu+2kv(uv+1)=0,\\
2mgv+2kv+2ku(uv+1)=0
$$
Dividing out an extra factor of 2 everywhere further gives
$$
mgu+kv(uv+1)=0, \\
(mg+k)v+ku(uv+1)=0
$$
If we multiply the top equation by $u$ and the bottom equation by $v$, we can subtract the two equations and we get
$$
mgu^2=(mg+k)v^2\implies u=\underbrace{\pm\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{mg}}}_{:=\alpha}v=\alpha v
$$
We return to the first equation and substitute $u$ to get
$$
mg\alpha v+kv(\alpha v^2+1)=0
$$
Notice immedietely that $v=0$ is a solution, and since $u=\alpha v$ we have $u=0$. This gives a candidate solution of $(u,v)=(0,0)$ which also implies $p=q=0$. Next we consider $v\neq 0$, and rearrange our equation to get
$$
k\alpha v^2+k+mg\alpha=0
$$
Notice that $\alpha$ took two different signs before; if we have $\alpha>0$, then this means that all terms present in this equation are positive. If we were to solve for $v$ we would notice that we require $v^2<0$, which is not possible, so $\alpha>0$ is not allowed and we must have $\alpha<0$. For sign interchanges, we now redefine $\alpha$ as
$$
\alpha:=\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{mg}}
$$
and the equation to solve is
$$
-k\alpha v^2+k-mg\alpha=0
$$
Solving for $v^2$ and replacing $\alpha$,
$$
v^2=\frac{k-mg\alpha}{k\alpha}=\frac{k-mg\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{mg}}}{k\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{mg}}}
$$
If we knew for a fact that there was only one equilibrium, then there should be no solutions for this. That is not the case, however, as the numerator (the sole computation that can change the sign of this fraction) can be positive or negative depending on $k,m,$ and $g$. Notice that as $k\to\infty$ the numerator diverges to $\infty$, and so we will have solutions beyond a critical threshold. We solve the numerator equal to zero to find this threshold.
$$
k-mg\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{mg}}=0\implies k^2=(mg)^2\left(1+\frac{k}{mg}\right)\implies k^2-(mg)k-(mg)^2=0 \\
\implies k=\frac{mg\pm\sqrt{(mg)^2+4(mg)^2}}{2}\implies k=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}mg=\underbrace{\varphi}_{\text{golden ratio!}}mg
$$
We dropped the subtracted term, since this would make $k$ negative. Thus, once $k$ exceeds this critical value a new equilibrium emerges. Importantly it emerges at the origin in $(u,v)$ space, since $k=\varphi mg$ corresponds to $v^2=0$. With $p=(u+v)/2$ and $q=(u-v)/2$,
$$
p=-\frac{\alpha-1}{2}v,\;\;\;\;q=-\frac{\alpha+1}{2}v, \\
\alpha=\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{mg}},\;\;\;\;v=\pm\sqrt{\frac{k-mg\alpha}{k\alpha}}
$$
Now, let's talk about stability, which can be done with the Hessian matrix
$$
H_V(p,q)=\begin{pmatrix}
2mg+3k+6kp^2-2kq^2 & -k-4kpq \\
-k-4kpq & 2mg-k-2kp^2+6kq^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The point $p=q=0$ is always an equilibrium, and its Hessian is
$$
H_V(0,0)=\begin{pmatrix}
2mg+3k & -k \\
-k & 2mg-k
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The matrix values we care about are
$$
\text{tr}(H_V)=2mg+2k>0, \\
\det(H_V)=(2mg+3k)(2mg-k)-k^2=4m^2g^2+4mgk-4k^2=-4\left[k^2-(mg)k-(mg)^2\right]
$$
If the trace and determinant are both positive, then the matrix is positive definite; this occurs for small $k$, but once $k$ exceeds $\varphi mg$ as before, this matrix changes since one eigenvalue becomes negative. This turns $p=q=0$ from a stable equilibrium to a saddle point, so it has a stable manifold but is generally unstable. Two new equilibria emerge (using the formulae above) and I don't want to do the algebra, but be assured that they are locally stable.
What does this mean phsycially? Well, if $k$ (the spring constant) is large enough, then the particles can find stablity other than at the bottom of their parabolas. This is because the spring force far exceeds the force of gravity and can hold the particles in place.

I agree with you with substitution but when we subtract after the substitution I think we got $2kuv+2k(uv+1)(u^2-v^2)$ and it's not obvious to me how to get $2kv^2 = 0$

@TurquoiseTilt I agree. I've been staring at this for a while now and realized that I got way ahead of myself from moving too quickly. I'll modify the post with an improved answer shortly.

I'm trying to work with your's and mine calculation but I'm afraid this won't end well. Maybe there's a smarter coordinates system that helps with uniqueness, from here I feel we're stuck :(
